# SFMC Custom Activity Execute endpoint only called at 1st version of a new journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I recently needed to migrate my Custom Activity of type message to another environment. Testing it now, I get some very weird behaviour.

When I create a new journey and call the custom activity for the 1st time, everything works perfectly, all the endpoints are called including the execute endpoint. In any higher version of the same journey without any changes, the execute endpoint is not called at all. In its stead, the publish endpoint is called a 2nd time.

I tried to adapt the endpoint of the installed package as well as to create a new one with the correct new endpoint from the beginning. Both behave the same way.

The Docker images on my old and new environments are almost the same, only the configured endpoints are different. On the old environment the execute endpoint is always called.

Log of my Service when the execute endpoint is not called

```
2021-11-11 09:09:28 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [a2bc2917-3ede-4dba-a42c-72bdc29862a7]Request from 161.71.32.15:
POST /myservicepath/publish
content-type: application/jwt 
x-forwarded-proto: https 
x-forwarded-port: 443 
host: myobscuredhostname.com
x-server-trace-id: Root=1-618cddc8-5d7e15c15a714188212a67d9 
content-length: 493 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICIxYzVmMTUyYS1kMGNmLTQ5MmUtODllNi00ZTYxYjcwM2FmMjQiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI2ODQ3NDFjMy1kMTRkLTQwYzctOGYwNi1mNzIzZTRjNDUyYTEiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNCIsDQogICJpc1B1Ymxpc2hlZCI6IGZhbHNlDQp9.CU5FD9ZFvjy-dJ0jIPx1ZT4qLwuRM5x_AyDhjmdlVxs
2021-11-11 09:09:28 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG c.t.o.c.controller.JwtController - Received Requests via /publish:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICIxYzVmMTUyYS1kMGNmLTQ5MmUtODllNi00ZTYxYjcwM2FmMjQiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI2ODQ3NDFjMy1kMTRkLTQwYzctOGYwNi1mNzIzZTRjNDUyYTEiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNCIsDQogICJpc1B1Ymxpc2hlZCI6IGZhbHNlDQp9.CU5FD9ZFvjy-dJ0jIPx1ZT4qLwuRM5x_AyDhjmdlVxs,
payload:
{
  "activityObjectID": "1c5f152a-d0cf-492e-89e6-4e61b703af24",
  "interactionId": "684741c3-d14d-40c7-8f06-f723e4c452a1",
  "originalDefinitionId": "433be492-8bbc-4d11-9ee8-2e823b0b1403",
  "interactionKey": "a53bc4b5-f6f4-4a24-c2f7-d11d544545a0",
  "interactionVersion": "4",
  "isPublished": false
}
2021-11-11 09:09:28 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-6] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [a2bc2917-3ede-4dba-a42c-72bdc29862a7] Response:
200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=93C05C18878A2D8E1AF4CC1886AF8F24; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly 
publish ok
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [3afe83d3-5de1-41fe-a635-bcd7f9293dcf]Request from 161.71.32.11:
POST /myservicepath/save
content-type: application/jwt 
x-forwarded-proto: https 
x-forwarded-port: 443 
host: myobscuredhostname.com
x-server-trace-id: Root=1-618cddc9-6d82e0073138e42a7fcf4175 
content-length: 460 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICJjNTExZmE5Ny03ZGU5LTRiY2ItODk4Yi1mNTg2M2RiOTBlYjYiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI1ZWU1OThiOS0wNTRhLTQ1ZGEtYWMyOS0yMzNlODUyM2E0MTgiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNSINCn0.1PhRCNFOya9yU1hHVEgUkJWmtfTq4axJX3qYrU7KQTQ
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.t.o.c.controller.JwtController - Received Requests via /save:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICJjNTExZmE5Ny03ZGU5LTRiY2ItODk4Yi1mNTg2M2RiOTBlYjYiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI1ZWU1OThiOS0wNTRhLTQ1ZGEtYWMyOS0yMzNlODUyM2E0MTgiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNSINCn0.1PhRCNFOya9yU1hHVEgUkJWmtfTq4axJX3qYrU7KQTQ,
payload:
{
  "activityObjectID": "c511fa97-7de9-4bcb-898b-f5863db90eb6",
  "interactionId": "5ee598b9-054a-45da-ac29-233e8523a418",
  "originalDefinitionId": "433be492-8bbc-4d11-9ee8-2e823b0b1403",
  "interactionKey": "a53bc4b5-f6f4-4a24-c2f7-d11d544545a0",
  "interactionVersion": "5"
}
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-9] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [3afe83d3-5de1-41fe-a635-bcd7f9293dcf] Response:
200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2906EB769E6CB5B0D94755A38F693B3F; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly 
save ok
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [7bb9da5b-6d83-4e54-abde-145a204b6bf1]Request from 161.71.32.11:
POST /myservicepath/validate
content-type: application/jwt 
x-forwarded-proto: https 
x-forwarded-port: 443 
host: myobscuredhostname.com
x-server-trace-id: Root=1-618cddc9-1ec0cd90496b348a2d1889b2 
content-length: 1232 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.EwzJM1val0D_DIQj7YWnZqCmxIgmkgOsQ5xMvg7D54g
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4] DEBUG c.t.o.c.controller.JwtController - Received Requests via /validate:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICJjNTExZmE5Ny03ZGU5LTRiY2ItODk4Yi1mNTg2M2RiOTBlYjYiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI1ZWU1OThiOS0wNTRhLTQ1ZGEtYWMyOS0yMzNlODUyM2E0MTgiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNSIsDQogICJpbkFyZ3VtZW50cyI6IFsNCiAgICB7DQogICAgICAidG9rZW4iOiAiIiwNCiAgICAgICJjcmVhdGlvbkRhdGVUaW1lIjogIjIwMjEtMTEtMTFUMDk6MDk6MjAuMzA0WiIsDQogICAgICAiY29udGFjdEtleSI6ICIiLA0KICAgICAgImpvdXJuZXlJZCI6ICIiLA0KICAgICAgImpvdXJuZXlOYW1lIjogIkFXUyBERVYgVGVzdCA1IiwNCiAgICAgICJqb3VybmV5VmVyc2lvbiI6IDAsDQogICAgICAiYWN0aXZpdHlJZCI6ICIiLA0KICAgICAgImFjdGl2aXR5TmFtZSI6ICJUZWxla29tIFNNUyAoZGVmYXVsdCBuYW1lKSIsDQogICAgICAieHNsVGVtcGxhdGUiOiAiPHhzbDpzdHlsZXNoZWV0IHZlcnNpb249XCIxLjBcIiB4bWxuczp4c2w9XCJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L1hTTC9UcmFuc2Zvcm1cIj48eHNsOm91dHB1dCBtZXRob2Q9XCJ0ZXh0XCIvPjx4c2w6dGVtcGxhdGUgbWF0Y2g9XCIvcm9vdFwiPlRlc3RcblxuZ2hndmg8L3hzbDp0ZW1wbGF0ZT48L3hzbDpzdHlsZXNoZWV0PiIsDQogICAgICAiYXR0cmlidXRlcyI6IHt9LA0KICAgICAgInRpbWVmcmFtZVByb2ZpbGUiOiAiQSINCiAgICB9DQogIF0NCn0.EwzJM1val0D_DIQj7YWnZqCmxIgmkgOsQ5xMvg7D54g,
payload:
{
  "activityObjectID": "c511fa97-7de9-4bcb-898b-f5863db90eb6",
  "interactionId": "5ee598b9-054a-45da-ac29-233e8523a418",
  "originalDefinitionId": "433be492-8bbc-4d11-9ee8-2e823b0b1403",
  "interactionKey": "a53bc4b5-f6f4-4a24-c2f7-d11d544545a0",
  "interactionVersion": "5",
  "inArguments": [
    {
      "token": "",
      "creationDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:09:20.304Z",
      "contactKey": "",
      "journeyId": "",
      "journeyName": "Journey Test 5",
      "journeyVersion": 0,
      "activityId": "",
      "activityName": "Activity Name",
      "xslTemplate": "template content",
      "attributes": 
{}
,
      "timeframeProfile": "A"
    }
  ]
}
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-4] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [7bb9da5b-6d83-4e54-abde-145a204b6bf1] Response:
200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4C7091177136382174A4FF81EC746F7E; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly 
validate ok
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [8add0217-1f66-4aaf-b49b-a2ef7213cb49]Request from 161.71.32.11:
POST /myservicepath/publish
content-type: application/jwt 
x-forwarded-proto: https 
x-forwarded-port: 443 
host: myobscuredhostname.com
x-server-trace-id: Root=1-618cddc9-432096812e988cfe418e4e6b 
content-length: 492 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICJjNTExZmE5Ny03ZGU5LTRiY2ItODk4Yi1mNTg2M2RiOTBlYjYiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI1ZWU1OThiOS0wNTRhLTQ1ZGEtYWMyOS0yMzNlODUyM2E0MTgiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNSIsDQogICJpc1B1Ymxpc2hlZCI6IHRydWUNCn0.wUY9yUgGfXpfOQPo5wvrs9ewWMXXY3Xpe-af2DFGYF8
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] DEBUG c.t.o.c.controller.JwtController - Received Requests via /publish:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ew0KICAiYWN0aXZpdHlPYmplY3RJRCI6ICJjNTExZmE5Ny03ZGU5LTRiY2ItODk4Yi1mNTg2M2RiOTBlYjYiLA0KICAiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25JZCI6ICI1ZWU1OThiOS0wNTRhLTQ1ZGEtYWMyOS0yMzNlODUyM2E0MTgiLA0KICAib3JpZ2luYWxEZWZpbml0aW9uSWQiOiAiNDMzYmU0OTItOGJiYy00ZDExLTllZTgtMmU4MjNiMGIxNDAzIiwNCiAgImludGVyYWN0aW9uS2V5IjogImE1M2JjNGI1LWY2ZjQtNGEyNC1jMmY3LWQxMWQ1NDQ1NDVhMCIsDQogICJpbnRlcmFjdGlvblZlcnNpb24iOiAiNSIsDQogICJpc1B1Ymxpc2hlZCI6IHRydWUNCn0.wUY9yUgGfXpfOQPo5wvrs9ewWMXXY3Xpe-af2DFGYF8,
payload:
{
  "activityObjectID": "c511fa97-7de9-4bcb-898b-f5863db90eb6",
  "interactionId": "5ee598b9-054a-45da-ac29-233e8523a418",
  "originalDefinitionId": "433be492-8bbc-4d11-9ee8-2e823b0b1403",
  "interactionKey": "a53bc4b5-f6f4-4a24-c2f7-d11d544545a0",
  "interactionVersion": "5",
  "isPublished": true
}
2021-11-11 09:09:29 [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5] DEBUG c.t.o.myservice.filter.LoggingFilter - [8add0217-1f66-4aaf-b49b-a2ef7213cb49] Response:
200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AE2256FB4F8A086A79FFCF86E3AC011B; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly 
publish ok
```

Config json

```
{
    "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
    "metaData": {
        "icon": "images/sms Env-DEV.png",
        "category": "message"
    },
    "type": "REST",
    "lang": {
        "en-US": {
            "name": "Env-DEV",
            "description": "Custom Activity Webapp"
        }
    },
    "arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "inArguments": [],
            "outArguments": [],
            "url": "https://endpoint.com/myservicepath/execute",
            "verb": "POST",
            "body": "",
            "header": "",
            "format": "json",
            "useJwt": true,
            "timeout": 100000,
            "retryCount": 5,
            "retryDelay": 100
        }
    },  
    "configurationArguments": {
        "save": {
            "url": "https://endpoint.com/myservicepath/save",
            "verb": "POST",
            "useJwt": true
        },
        "publish": {
            "url": "https://endpoint.com/myservicepath/publish",
            "verb": "POST",
            "useJwt": true
        },
        "validate": {
            "url": "https://endpoint.com/myservicepath/validate",
            "verb": "POST",
            "useJwt": true
        },
        "TestSave": {
            "url": "https://endpoint.com/myservicepath/testSave",
            "verb": "POST",
            "useJwt": true
        }
    },
    "userInterfaces": {
        "configModal": {            
            "height": 200,
            "width": 300,
            "fullscreen": true
        }
    },  
    "schema": {
        "arguments": {
            "execute": {
                "inArguments": [],
                "outArguments": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the setting for contact entry in the journey set to no reentry.